# Android support library wrong version

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have a problem while building my android project due to some missing android-support-library (i.e: android-support-v7.jar) so to fix it I had to add an Android Support Library from eclipse wizard. However I was surprised that my `$android_sdk_home/extras/andoird/support/v7/appcompact/libs` contains `android-support-v4.jar` and `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you're wondering if having both v4 and v7 support libraries is normal. It is perfectly normal as they have different purposes. Basically they provide you with widgets and APIs to be used respectively in API levels 4 and 7 and beyond. They also provide different interfaces.

You can read about it here in more detail: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I thought actually it should be android-support-v7.jar rather than android-support-v4.jar since it's a v7/appcompat/libs repository. Isn't it the case or am I wrong?

Comment: Please check out the link I provided above. v4 comes as a one library whereas v7 comes in many libraries. One for CardView, one for AppCompat stuff, one for preferences etc That's why it's named differently. I hope it clears everything out. If so, please accept the answer and vote. It means much here :).